# How can I pass floating point numbers as template parameters?

Tags: c++

I am working on a meta-programming project, and we would like to have the ability to pass floating-point numbers as template arguments. I wasn't sure whether this question would be better suited to Stack Exchange, but I figured it's a somewhat conceptual so opted for this site.

Basically, I want to do this:

```
template <double var>
double fun() { return var; }

int main()
{
  double myDoble = fun<1.0>();
  return 0;
}
```

Obviously, this can't be done. This link (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) makes it clear that the type passed as a template argument must be one of the following:

```
integral type
enumeration
pointer to object or to function
lvalue reference to object or to function
pointer to member object or to member function
std::nullptr_t (since C++11)
```

However, the fact that I can pass a pointer to an object (perhaps a pointer to a struct containing a double?) makes me wonder that there might be a way of achieving the above by passing a pointer to such a double.

So I tried this:

```
template <double* pVar>
double fun()
{
    return *pVar;
}

int main() {
    static const double param = 1.2;
    double value = fun<&param>();
    return 0;
}
```

which gives the following error:

```
prog.cpp:9:29: error: ‘& param’ is not a valid template argument of type ‘double*’ because ‘param’ has no linkage
  double value = fun<&param>();
```

I thought that the issue might be that I'm using a primitive, so I tried this:

```
struct D
{
    double val;
};

template <D* pD>
double fun()
{
    return pD->val;
}

int main() {
    static const D d{1.2};

    double value = fun<&d>();
    return 0;
}
```

which gives the same error.

Does anyone have other ideas for approaching this problem? I would appreciate it if people could refrain from "it can't be done" answers; I know it can't be done, I want to do it anyway! ;)

Comment: Make it a global. PS: You can use references instead of pointers.

Comment: @ThomasEding I can't get that to work; http://ideone.com/LGDv1j

Comment: why you need it? why it must be done at compile time (i.e. use template)? maybe it is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: cppreference gets into more detail at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments

Comment: The point of templates is to support multiple types. A template with one type is called a function. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @BillDoor I'm trying to create a meta programming language. In the application itself the templates are on classes, not functions. These are singletons.

Comment: Apparently, from the recent Belfast meeting, floating points will be allowed for non-type template arguments in C++20.  https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/dtuov8/201911_belfast_iso_c_committee_trip_report/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
template <double* pVar>
double fun()
{
    return *pVar;
}

double param = 1.2;

int main() {
   double value = fun<&param>();
   return 0;
}
```

I'm using g++ 4.8.2.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to pass double's to templated function, you should use a wrapper.
Like this one:

```
struct D
{
    operator double(){ return 1.2; }
};

template <typename T>
double fun()
{
    T t;
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    double value = fun<D>();
    return 0;
}
```

but maybe more useful is to define a macro like this:

```
#define DBLWRAPPER(dbl) typedef struct { operator double(){ return dbl; } }

int main()
{
    DBLWRAPPER(1.2) DBL1_2;
    DBLWRAPPER(2.45) DBL2_45;

    double value1_2 = fun<DBL1_2>();
    double value2_45 = fun<DBL2_45>();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that only objects with linkage can be used as template non-type address arguments, we can see this by going to the draft C++ standard section `14.3.2` *Template non-type arguments* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter
>   shall be one of:

and include the following bullet:

> a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object
>   with static storage duration **and external or internal linkage** or a
>   function with external or internal linkage [...]

Which is exactly what your error says:

> [...]because ‘param’ has no linkage

and we can see that block scope variables with some exceptions have no linkage, this is covered in section `3.5` *Program and linkage* which says:

> Names not covered by these rules have no linkage. Moreover, except as
>   noted, a name declared at block scope (3.3.3) has no linkage. A type
>   is said to have linkage if and only if:

and does not include any exceptions for this case.

Declaring it globally, would solve your issue in this case:

```
static double param = 1.2;

int main()
{
    double value = fun<&param>();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want `*pVar` to be a compile-time constant for the purposes of optimising `fun()` and using it where only a constant is accept (e.g. as a template parameter or array dimension), you need to accept it as `const double* const` and make `param` be `constexpr` (code below also at [ideone.com here](http://ideone.com/3PpmO9))...

```
template <int n>
struct S { };

template <const double* const pVar>
double fun()
{
    S<(int)*pVar> s;
    return *pVar;
}

constexpr double param = 1.2;

int main()
{
   double value = fun<&param>();
}
```

Note that if different places in your code provide the template with pointers to distinct `double`s having the same value, you will probably get distinct instantiations in your executable (i.e. pointless "code bloat", failed attempts at specialisation...).

Answer (score 0):

A solution for C++11 (encode the float into int):

```
constexpr int f2i_scaler = 100000;
constexpr int operator"" _i(long double v)
{
    return v * f2i_scaler < std::numeric_limits<int>::max() ||
                   v * f2i_scaler > std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest()
               ? v * f2i_scaler
               : throw std::invalid_argument("Overflow!");
}

template <int n>
struct S {
   void show(){
       std::cout << (double)n/f2i_scaler << "\n";
   }
};

S<1.5_i> s;
```